# Hibernate: org.hibernate.WrongClassException

Tags: hibernate

i am banging my head because of the following issue:

I have 2 entity clases inheriting a base class. the base class simply stores create/update dates.

BASECLASS:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class BaseEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "CREATED", nullable = true)
private Date created;

@PrePersist
protected void onCreate() {
    created = new Date();
}

...
```

Subclass 1:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel")
@XmlRootElement
public class Hotel extends BaseEntity implements Serializable
...
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "hotel", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private Set<HotelManager> hotelManagers = new HashSet<HotelManager>();
...
```

Subclass 2:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "hotel_manager")
public class HotelManager extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

...
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "hotel_id", nullable = false)
private Hotel hotel;
....
```

Whenever i try to load a hotel entity i get the following error:

**org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 7 was not of the specified subclass: de.hop.entity.HotelManager (loaded object was of wrong class class de.hop.entity.Hotel)**

Side note: by chance the hotel row id (unique id) and as well the hotelmanager row id are both '7' in both of the db tables

Any ideas???

Comment: please add the code where you load the entity.and why are you using the @inheraticance annotation. you can add @ MappedSuperclass to your base class.

Comment: Try setting your fetch type to lazy for the hotel manager set in hotel. Most likely, the problem is in trying to load the hotel manager's eagerly associated with the hotel.

Comment: @si mo that solved my issue. thanks!

Comment: :-) i added a answer. can you please flag it as anwer? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `@ MappedSuperclass` instead of `@Inheritance` to your base class.

Comment: This answer is misleading, as when doing so: "org.hibernate.AnnotationException An entity cannot be annotated with both @Entity and @MappedSuperclass". So it should read "instead of @Entity" in your answer? Please check/clarify.